# Jax-RS : extracting specific header from head call response?

Tags: java, dictionary, header, jax-rs, keyset

I have the following code:

```
MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = requestBuilder.build("persons", queryParams).head().getHeaders();

//print all headers for trace
for(Object header : headers.keySet()){
  System.out.println(header);
 }
```

What is the most `efficient` way to extract one header: i.e. "count" from the above map of header responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get it from the map by the key name:

```
headers.get("count")
```